# ping computers on a network with javascript

Tags: javascript, networking, ping

I have a php page that displays a map of computers in a network (and some info about the working config) and i want to see wich are up when i open this map in my browser.
Is it possible to ping another computer from the same network with javascript and post the result on page load automatically?

Answer (score 0):

If that computer you want to ping is also running an HTTP server, or a server on another protocol that the browser can talk to - then yes, you can send them a message and wait for a response. That requires cooperation fro the network.

Otherwise, you can't send ICMP (Internet Control Message Protocol) requests directly from JavaScript. You'd need some backend on one of the computers your JS can talk to and send the data from there (and talk to that, probably with HTTP, WebSockets or another thing JS talks to).